# Bizarre: css font makes element move position

Tags: css

I have bizarre css behavior. I have a div container (#right-input) that houses a textarea and button and they pop out of #userinput container if I do not delete the `font: x-small arial,helvetica,sans-serif;` in a body tag that I have. Anyone have any ideas? How can a font declaration affect an element like that?

```
body { 
    font: x-small arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    background: #000;
    margin:0;
text-align:center;
}
#userinput {
    font-size:130%;
color: #333;
    margin:10px auto 10px auto;
    padding:10px;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    width:570px;
height:135px;
    position:relative;
z-index:9999;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:7px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:7px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:7px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:7px;

opacity: 0.85;
    /* for IE */
  filter:alpha(opacity=85);
}
#right-input{
        clear:left;
float:right;
width:480px;
}



  <div id="userinput">
    <div id="right-input">    
        Send a message to others watching!
        <form id="form" action="form.php?action=add" method="post"> 

                    <TEXTAREA id="message" class="limited" name="message" maxlength="1000" COLS="45" ROWS="6"></TEXTAREA>
            <br>
<input id="send" type="submit" value="Send!" />     
        </form>

    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the html as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your current code, if you resize `#right-input`, it doesn't adjust `#userinput` because `#right-input` is floated which takes it out of the document flow.

Try changing your html to this:

```
<div id="userinput">
    <div id="right-input">    
        Send a message to others watching!
        <form id="form" action="form.php?action=add" method="post"> 

            <TEXTAREA id="message" class="limited" name="message" maxlength="1000" COLS="45" ROWS="6"></TEXTAREA>
            <br>
            <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send!" />     
        </form>

    </div>

    <!-- added div to clear float -->
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>

</div>
```

It should make sure that your `textarea` will stay inside its `div`.

Comment: I appreciate it kei, it turned out to be a different element all together. CSS is so annoying! There was an element that if I left display:none on, it made this one come out +1 thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1):

If you say that font: x-small causes the problem, try to replace it with

```
font-size: 14px; /* 14px - for example */
font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
```

Comment: The bigger I make the font, the more it goes in but then all my other fonts get really big. I guess I will have to change each font which is pretty dumb though it seems...

Comment: OK, but I can not see left input. Right input works fine alone.

Comment: I appreciate it Webars, it turned out to be a different element all together. CSS is so annoying! There was an element that if I left display:none on, it made this one come out +1 thanks anyway though.